# ¿Como añadir archivos de audio al crear un instalador en Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, audio

Tengo una aplicación básica en donde al accionar un  boton este reproduce un audio, pero cuando creo el instalador y lo instalo en otro pc este dice que no se encuentran los archivos de audio, ¿tendre que agregar otro resultado del proyecto en el Application Folder del creador del instalador?

Answer (score 0):

Depende de la forma en que estés publicando tu instalador. Si estás utilizando ClickOnce para hacer tu instalador y no estás utilizando el apartado de "Recursos" en las propiedades de tu proyecto, entonces es probable que necesites especificar que el archivo sea copiado siempre a tu carpeta. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le das click derecho al archivo para acceder a la ventana de propiedades y en donde dice "Copiar en el directorio de salida", selecciona "Copiar siempre".

También a la hora de hacer tu publicación con ClickOnce asegúrate que en el apartado de "Archivos de la aplicación" tu archivo esté marcado como "Incluir siempre" como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]